# next js in litespeed webserver

Tags: webserver, vps

I have a Next.js application installed on my VPS, and when I run it using `yarn start`, it starts on port `3040`. I would like to know how to configure it to start on ports `80` and `443` instead. Thank you!

Comment: The answer should be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147499/how-to-set-port-in-next-js.